# Почему не работает JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

Я только начал свой путь в Java. Столкнулся с проблемой когда начал работать с JavaFX. В Файле sample.fxml лежит код :

```xml
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" 
      alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

Ошибкой подсвечивает `fx:controller="sample.Controller"`
и `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"`

У меня стоит JDK8. Пишу код в Intellij-idea. Не знаю как убрать эти ошибки, помогите.
Фотка есть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, что IDEA не видит класс контроллера, возможно он находится не в пакете sample, а где-то в другом месте. Чтобы сказать точно, нужно видеть структуру вашего проекта. Вообще, IDE при наведении на ошибку обычно показывает, что именно не так.

Comment: На папке src нажмите правой кнопкой и выберите `Mark Directory as` -> `Sources Root`.

Comment: Вообще, у вас что-то не то с проектом. У вас в IDE открыто два файла iml (проекта Intellij IDEA), но в дереве ни одного из них нет. Если с нуля сгенерировать проект JavaFX, то и директории будут правильно размечены, и красным ничего подсвечивать не будет на таком fxml файле.

Comment: @insolor, удалил все файлы и все создал по новой. В прошлый раз не помогало, но сейчас каким то чудом помогло. В любом случае спасибо!